# ¿Como hacer un filtrado en un DropDownListFor?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera saber como le puedo hacer para que mi DropDownListFor me haga un filtrado de los datos que tengo cargados ahí, ya que son muchos y no quiero ir buscando uno por uno, quisiera que al momento de ir escribiendo me vayan saliendo las coincidencias de lo que vaya texteando.

HTML5

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdFarmacia)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdFarmacia, new SelectList(ViewBag.Farmacias, "IdFarmacia", "Nombre_Farmacia"), "Seleccionar", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdFarmacia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solamente con código razor o html no podrías hacerlo, así que tienes dos opciones:

- la primera sería crear dicha funcionalidad vos mismo con javascript.
- la segunda sería utilizar algún plugin o librería de javascript que
  te permite realizarlo con muy poco código.

Personalmente te recomiendo que te vayas con la segunda opción ya que te vas a ahorrar mucho código y por ende mucho tiempo.

Una de las librerías que podrías utilizar es [esta](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/). Y la forma de utilizarlo es un poco simple. Tienes que incluir jQuery y bootstrap en tu vista y el archivo css y el js del plugin y luego agregarle la clase "selectpicker" al elemento html (dropdown) en el cual deseas activarlo, y para que te permita realizar búsqueda en dicho elemento solamente debes agregar el atributo `data-live-search="true"` a dicho elemento.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```